# Apache is not running from XAMPP Control Panel ( Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. ) Apache says httpd.exe -System error (.dll file missing)

Tags: php, apache

I've just re-installed XAMPP, and when I try to start my Apache server
 in the XAMPP Control Panel, I now get the following errors:

```
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64-bit
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    XAMPP Version: 7.0.8
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.2  [ Compiled: Nov 12th 2015 ]
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
     12:28:34 PM  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
     12:28:39 PM  [main]    All prerequisites found
     12:28:39 PM  [main]    Initializing Modules
     12:28:39 PM  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
     12:28:39 PM  [main]    Control Panel Ready
     12:28:42 PM  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
     12:28:43 PM  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
     12:29:36 PM  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
     12:29:36 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
     12:29:36 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
     12:29:36 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
     12:29:36 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
     12:29:36 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
     12:29:36 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
     12:29:36 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Apache runs on port 80, there might be some software running on port 80,close that software and then try. Most likely culprit is Skype if you have it in your system

Comment: Which dll file was missing? Have you tried running it as Administrator (as the log suggests)?

Comment: when i start apache then show me a box in which httpd.exe - system Error   the massege is that {The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. }    and i reinstalling it two times  and download it again but it not working now ...